# Where should I put unhandled exception handler?

Tags: c#, winforms, exception

I have some piece of code called `Finally()` which handles unhandled exceptions by subscribing to `UnhandledException` event (I'm talking about WinForms).

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += (_, __) => Finally(__.ExceptionObject as Exception);
```

Where should I put this line? Into the `static Program()` constructor or into the `static void Main()` method? Is there any differences?

Comment: you can subscribe anywhere in the `Main` method but before an `unhandled exception` has occured.

Comment: Are you looking for this [UnhandledException](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8148174/1257607)?

Comment: Also, this can do the trick for you: [Application.SetUnhandledExceptionMode Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.setunhandledexceptionmode(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although they both are called in the beginning of your program, I would place it in the `Main()` method because any exceptions that occur from within the static constructor are harder to debug.